# Spark reading Avro file

Tags: scala, apache-spark, avro, spark-avro

I'm using com.databricks.spark.avro. When I run it from spark-shell like so: `spark-shell --jar spark-avro_2.11-4.0.0.jar`, I am able to read the file by doing this:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)
val avroInput = sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.avro").load(inputPath)
avroInput.write.format("com.databricks.spark.avro").save(outputPath)
```

But if I try to do the same thing from my project using `sbt clean run`, I get:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source: org.apache.spark.sql.avro.AvroFileFormat. Please find packages at http://spark.apache.org/third-party-projects.html
[info]   at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:657)
[info]   at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:194)
[info]   at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:178)
[info]   at com.databricks.spark.avro.package$AvroDataFrameReader$$anonfun$avro$2.apply(package.scala:34)
```

`"com.databricks"               %% "spark-avro"           % "4.0.0"` is listed in my Dependencies and it's in my external libraries. Is there another dependency I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out I didn't have to use the databricks jar. I added apache spark avro to my dependencies:

```
"org.apache.spark"             %% "spark-avro"           % "2.4.0"
```

And I was able to read my avro file into a `DataFrame`:

```
val avroInput = sparkSession.read
  .format("avro")
  .load("/pathtoFile/avroFile.avro")
```

Answer (score 5):

Below are the dependencies you would need while using Avro in Spark. based on your need, use one of the following.

**Maven dependencies.**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-avro_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

**spark-submit**

While using spark-submit, provide spark-avro_2.12 and its dependencies directly using --packages, such as,

```
./bin/spark-submit --packages org.apache.spark:spark-avro_2.12:2.4.4
```

**spark-shell**

While working with  spark-shell, you can also use --packages to add spark-avro_2.12 and its dependencies directly,

```
./bin/spark-shell --packages org.apache.spark:spark-avro_2.12:2.4.4
```

Change the spark-avro version according to the version you are using.

Refer [Using Avro Data Files From Spark SQL 2.4.x and later](https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/read-write-avro-file-spark-dataframe/)
Happy Learning !!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-avro.html#deploying to see how deploy Avro jar along with your application jar through `spark-submit` command. Specifically, you need to use `--packages` option. This also works for `spark-shell`.

Comment: I'm trying to include with the application and get it working with `sbt clean test` or `sbt clean run`. It works if I execute the commands in spark-shell with the packages option, but it doesn't work with `sbt clean test` or `sbt clean run`.